# IE Automation Book or Resource?? using MSHTML/ShDocVw VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, automation, mshtml, shdocvw

Can anyone recommend a book or a website that explains Internet Explorer Automation using VB.NET? I understand that mshtml and ShDocVw.dll can do this, but I need a resource that will explain it to me. I want to read/write values as well as click buttons.

The only book I have come across so far is .Net Test Automation Recipes. Is this the one for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net/index.html) if you want some source code that goes in depth in terms of automating IE.  In fact it may do exactly what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

The only book I am aware of dedicated to this subject at the IE COM level is 
the digital Wrox publication [Introduction to programming Internet Explorer in C#](http://www.certificationworks.com/books/B00007FYZP.htm) by Nikit Zykov. Although the examples are in C# the content is just as useful for VB.NET programmers. But as already mentioned you would probably be better off using one of the simpler IE COM wrapper APIs such as [WatiN](http://watin.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 0):

Check this article : 
Internet Explorer Late Binding Automation
Internet Explorer automation sample code using late binding, without Microsoft.mshtml and shdocvw dependency.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/IELateBindingAutowod.aspx